# parseInt() acting strangely after substring operation to remove characters

Tags: java, string, parseint

I've been trying to read text from a page using a scanner. I need to store one of the fields on the page as an int, and I've noticed when the scanner gets to the last integer on the line, it also picks up text that isn't separated by whitespace. To fix this issue, I have the following code:

```
String x=sc.next();//sc is the scanner
x=x.substring(0,x.length()-4);//the text is always 4 characters long
int x=Integer.parseInt(x);
```

This code throws a `NumberFormatException`. I've tried removing 5 characters off the end to see if I was making a silly error but it ended up removing part of the number. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example of the text that will be inputted into the program?

Comment: something along the lines of 3495845997qwer

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `3495845997` isn't an `int`.  Integers in Java have a maximum value of `2147483647`.  Try using `Long.parseLong(x)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The number that you are parsing is too big to be contain in an Integer. Try this

```
long y=Long.parseLong(x);
```